# Como colocar uma modal bootstrap pequena sobre outra modal maior com o esmaecer funcionando corretamente nos dois fundos?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, modal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho duas modal bootstrap , a primeira uma modal-xl, a segunda uma modal-sm que é menor , elas abrem normalmente .
Porém a primeira da o efeito de esmaecer certinho, já quando abro a segunda a modal abaixo que é maior não dá o efeito esmaecer.

Com isso, pode que o usuário se confunda, pois as duas modais ficam com visibilidade iguais.
Preciso que ao abrir a segunda modal, a primeira fique esmaecida.

Comment: Cara coloca um mínimo de código ai de forma que de para pelo menos a gente simular o seu problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meu caro, você pode estar resolvendo o seu problema dessa maneira, no bootstrap, incluíndo duas funções que fazem a modificação no css do modal, em diferentes eventos:

```js
 function esconderModalFundo(){
      $('#exampleModal').css('z-index', '0');
    }

    function mostrarModalFundo(){
      $('#exampleModal').css('z-index', '1050');
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Teste de modal</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Abrir modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg p-5" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2" onclick="esconderModalFundo()">Abrir segunda modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade xl-12" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Segunda Modal </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" onclick="mostrarModalFundo()" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="mostrarModalFundo()">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



  
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Resolveu meu problema perfeitamente, muito agradecido.

Comment: Para que o z-index da primeira modal se ajuste  quando o usuário fechar a segunda  clicando apenas fora dela e não no 'X' pode utilizar o código abaixo

$('#exampleModal2').on("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {
   $('#exampleModal').css('z-index', '1050');
})